# Javascript Type Error, is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got abit of a strange problem, that I just can't seem to solve! It's part of a big framework I'm writing, but I've wrote some test code which has the same problem. See the following:

```
!function ($, window, undefined) {

    // BASE FUNCTION
    var test = function (selector, context) {
        return new test.fn.init(selector, context);
    };

    // SELECTOR FUNCTIONS
    test.fn = {
        selector:   undefined,
        init:       function (selector, context) {
            // Use jQuery to build selector object
            this.selector = $(selector, context);
            return this;
        },

        // Create a popup dialog
        popup:      function (options) {
            this.selector.dialog();
        }
    },

    // Expose Carbon to the global object
    window.test     = test;

}(window.jQuery, window);
```

Now when I use the following:

```
test('#popupLink').popup();
```

I get "TypeError: test("#popupLink").popup is not a function". I know it's partly working, as I can do use standard jQuery functions if I do something like:

```
test('#popupLink').selector.hide();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm having a mental block right now.
Thanks in advance! :)

**Update**

I've used console.log to view the returned object, and it only has the selector element in, which makes sense as I didn't use prototype. How can I fix that?

Comment: Change test.fn to test.prototype or test.fn.prototype

Comment: I've added "test.fn.prototype = test.fn", but it still doesn't work, exactly the same error :(

Comment: You must assign popup to the  prototype of test.fn.init.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(function ($, window) {
    // BASE FUNCTION
    var test = function (selector, context) {
        return new test.fn.init(selector, context);
    };

    // SELECTOR FUNCTIONS
    test.fn = test.prototype = {
        constructor: test,
        init: function (selector, context) {
            // Use jQuery to build selector object
            this.selector = $(selector, context);
            return this;
        },

        // Create a popup dialog
        popup: function (options) {
            console.log('popup');
            return this;
        }
    };

    // Expose test to the global object
    window.test = test;
}(window.jQuery, window));

test.fn.init.prototype = test.fn;
```

You missed the constructor and the prototype chain on the created instances of test.

Comment: Actually one more thing, what does "constructor: test" do in this case?

Comment: Actually, nevermind worked it out. If you do "new test()", it uses the original test function as the constructor. d'oh!

Comment: Returns a reference to the function that created the instance's prototype. Changes it from Object to test, you can remove it if you don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was while adding integration tests and I didn't notice that the function I am trying to call belongs to a mocked class. It is easy to get confused because when trying to navigate (I am using IntelliJ) the IDE goes to the implemented function.

Mocking the function mentioned in the error resolved that.